# Help with readings on schematic

Tags: diy

I am in a Kenwood TK805D and a Kenwood TM241A to interface some of the hidden inner circuitry with the outside world so I can use the radios to do more than just talk on (ex. AllStar node, cross band repeater, packet radio, and much more.)

I think I have found the place where I need to interface wires, but I am having trouble interpreting the abbreviations on the schematic. Can anybody help? Below are some connectors where I am looking into interface:

I obviously understand some of them, for example Mic is microphone input, but some (especially the single digit letters) are confusing including E and B, which I am thinking is battery.

**On the [Kenwood TM241A](http://file:///Users/skylerfennell/Desktop/TM-241%20Service%20Manual.pdf)** (svc manual)

[image]

**On the [Kenwood TK805D](http://www.rfstuff.com/manuals/805Dman.pdf)**(svc manual)

[image]

Can Anybody help interperet the pinouts of the particular connectors?

Answer (score 1):

E is "earth", better known in north America as "ground".
A1 and A2 are audio lines, as evidenced by connection to the volume control.

On the rest, I can only guess. 
CK for "clock"
EN for "enable"
TX for "transmit"
DT for "data"
SQ for "squelch"

If you were to study the circuit at the other end of these wires, it would help fill in the missing bits.

Comment: And in keeping with convention, NC is obviously 'No Connection'